# Specific Youtube Video Gives Error when play in desktop application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5, swfloader

Description:

I have a youtube player in My Desktop Application. I implement it by using `SWFLoader` and using this url `http://www.youtube.com/v/yd71LWhCO4s?version=3&autoplay=0&autohide=0&fs=1&showinfo=0` it works. 'yd71LWhCO4s' is a Video id, if I change it to `FqJdzYY_Fas` then it gives me an error.

```
`Error #2044: Unhandled adError:. text=Failed to load resource: Error
Load Never Completed. URL: 
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/gadgets/overlay/OverlayTemplate.swf.
```

I get the url from the error message and i am interested to know about the swf at this URL. So i use this url directly in my browser, and my  firewall blocked it due to advertising of Google. If I click on 'dismiss all' then the video playes.

I want to remove this error, how can I do that?